# Как оформить: вводное слово относится к определению

Tags: вводные-слова, определения

Дано предложение:

*...ведь дополнительный стенной проем означает и проникновение **ночного, но главное – зимнего** холода в дом.*

Какие есть **варианты** оформления, закрепленные **в правилах**?

Это однородные определения? Ночного и зимнего?

Comment: Sharon, а на мой вопрос не ответите? (Про этот не смогу ничего сказать.)

Comment: Попробую, но  чуть позже, наверное. В течение дня.

Comment: Спасибо большое заранее!)

Comment: Вопрос о "но главное" или о "ночного — зимнего"?

Comment: Вопрос о  знаках препинания для того случая, если ничего не менять в тексте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь:
Слово *главное* в значении ‘*особенно важно; особенно существенно*’ является вводным и выделяется запятыми:
*Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно.

Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно* — запятую после союза *а* поставить нельзя, и для усиления выделения после вводного сочетания поставлено тире.
*Как крупный учёный, а главное как историк искусства, он пользуется большим авторитетом* — вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122

Варианты оформления такие:
*...ведь дополнительный стенной проем означает и проникновение ночного, но главное, зимнего холода в дом.*
*...ведь дополнительный стенной проем означает и проникновение ночного, но главное – зимнего холода в дом.* || Тире интонационно подчёркивает вот это главное, а заодно и добавляет ударение вводному слову.
Для вводных слов типа "*главное*", "*более того*", указывающих на важность информации (что создаёт контраст), характерно тире.
*...ведь дополнительный стенной проем означает и проникновение ночного, но, главное, зимнего холода в дом.* || Союз "*но*" относится к прилагательному, после него есть пауза.

Думаю, что это однородные определения. Сочетание "*ночной зимний холод*" вызывает сомнения. Без паузы прочитать трудно. Прилагательные обозначают время: зимой и ночью.

Comment: Почему вы решили на А заменить?

Comment: Я пока исправила текст: ночного, а главное, зимнего холода в дом. Обычно используется союз А, почему здесь НО?  Мне нужны ПРИМЕРЫ  для обособления вводного слова запятой и тире, когда оно относится к прилагательным. Читается авторский вариант не намного лучше, а выглядит странно, неестественно.

Comment: Про союзы: НО - противительный, А - сопоставительный. А смысл такой: ночью всегда холодно (зимой и летом), но зимой холодно особенно и в любое время суток.

Comment: "*Но*" создаёт более резкий контраст. На мой взгляд, оно звучит удачно и интересно. Тире при вводных словах интонационное. Обязательным оно не является. Поэтому в справочниках это мало рассматривается. Ошибкой это тире являться не может. Но нужно учитывать целесообразность. С одной стороны, подчеркнуть главное - хорошо, а с другой - это всего лишь одно слово.

Comment: Мне не нравится графическое оформление, нужно увидеть такой же вариант. Поэтому пока спасибо  в 10 баллов.

Comment: И ещё важной причиной постановки тире является то, что после некоторых вводных слов подсознательно подставляется слово ЭТО (как здесь). А разве в пунктуации нужно рассматривать графический аспект? Она же не для рисунка используется.

Comment: Ладно, будем пока считать, что конструкция "а значит" может выглядеть как "но значит", а тире можно использовать для обособления. Противительный союз НО, вероятно, говорит о том, что главное - это не ночной холод, а зимний. Он как бы отрицает важность ночного холода, в то время как союз А только сопоставляет их. Спасибо.

Comment: Обычно люди мыслят так (про пунктуацию): запрещают ли это правила? Вы ищете наоборот: разрешают ли это правила и делают ли так другие. Нестандартность в любом случае не является ошибкой. Это придаёт изюминку.

Comment: Валгина (еще очень давно) сказала, что в пунктуации практика опережает теорию. Нельзя жить по правилам, написанным 30 - 40 лет назад, да и в новой редакции ничего хорошего и нового нет. Я же наблюдаю за развитием грамматических моделей, мне важно, насколько они востребованы в современной литературе. Никакие изюминки меня не интересуют. Мне нужны модели, по которым желательно строить текст, как новые, так и утвержденные в правилах.

Comment: Ясно, прикольно. Но развивают грамматические модели новаторы, а быть ним - ещё круче.

Comment: Не новаторы, а авторы (с их чувством языка)  и их продвинутые редакторы, которые не боятся нарушать формальные правила.

Comment: Для меня это новаторство (хоть и непреднамеренное).

Comment: Разница между запятой и тире: *ночного, но главное, что зимнего холода; ночного, но главное –  это зимнего холода*. При тире связь с вводным словом значительно сильнее.